# How to get my negative top margin to be consistent in desktop Safari?

Tags: css, safari, margin

I've added a negative margin to the logo of my site and it appears fine in all browsers I've tested to this point. See here:

[image: Other Browser Logo - Perfect]

The problem is it's not displaying right in Safari desktop. See here:

[image: Safari Logo - Too High]

The HTML is as follows:

```
<hgroup id="logo_container">
    <div id="logo_inside_container">
        <h1 id="site-title"><a href="<?php echo esc_url( home_url( '/' ) ); ?>" title="<?php echo esc_attr( get_bloginfo( 'name', 'display' ) ); ?>" rel="home"><img src="/wp-content/uploads/logo.png" alt="612 Vineyard - Berryville, VA"/></a></h1>
    </div>
</hgroup>
```

The CSS is as follows:

```
#site-title {
margin-top: -30px;
display: block;
padding: 0;
width: 190px;
height: 143px;
float: left;
}
#site-title img {
    width: 190px;
    height: 143px;
}
#logo_container {
    display: block;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    margin: -29px 0 0 !important;
    background: url('/wp-content/uploads/logo_stripe_bg.png') 0 41px repeat-x;
}
#logo_inside_container {
    display: block;
    width: 860px;
    height: 143px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    background: url('/wp-content/uploads/logo_stripe.png') 0 41px no-repeat;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I found a way to add browser specific classes to my body class here: http://codebyte.dev7studios.com/post/4180628671/add-browser-to-body-class-in-wordpress

Simply changed #site-title { margin-top: -30px; } to .safari #site-title { margin-top: 0; }

Hope this helps someone!